# Legality of using trademarked text on a T-Shirt

Tags: copyright, trademark

I was wondering how legal it would be to, say, sell T-Shirts with "Star Wars" written on them. I wouldn't be using the logo; I'd be using Helvetica. Is this fair game?

Answer (score 1):

This would not be legal because it would infringe upon their trademark without a license.